# Sharing a DataSet among different forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, dataset

I have created a DataSet with multiple tables.  I use a few tables on one form, and then 2 other tables on 2 other forms.  When I try to do the binding of the data, I cannot figure out how to have all 3 forms refer to the same DataSet object.  In the interface (Visual Studio Express 2013) I can select from the Project Data Sources list and get my MainDataSet class and then select whichever table I want.  But if I do this, I get a new object.  None of the other options seem to allow me to pick an already existing object.  I thought I used to see an option to pick my MainDataSet object from somewhere, but I don't currently see that option and even so, it didn't allow me to select a table anyway.

I know I could look closer at the binding code and figure out how to make this work, but since some of that code is in the Designer file, I can't modify it so it seems the best I can do if I do this is replace what it did with new bindings.  And it seems like I shouldn't have to do this.  There HAS to be a way to do this in the Visual Studio GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on SLaks' suggestion, here is what I did.

1. I dragged a `BindingSource` onto a form and named it `sharedDataSource`.
2. In the Properties of the `BindingSource` I set the `DataSource` by selected `MyDataSet` class under the Project Data Sources heading.  I believe this created the `DataSource` object and bound it to the `BindingSource`.
3. In the designer I chose the data source for the the `DataGridView` objects by selecting `sharedDataSource` and then the appropriate table under that.
4. For the `DataGridView`s in the second form I selected Other Data Sources-->Project Data Sources-->`MyDataSet`.
5. I created a constructor for the second form that takes a `MyDataSet` object as a parameter.  In the constructor I set both `SomethingOrOtherBindingSource.DataSource` and `mainDataSet` to the paramater.  I think the former is required, but the latter may only be required if you refer to it in your code.
6. When I create the second form (from the first form), I passed in `sharedDataSource` to the constructor.

So in the designer a data source is bound to the grid and you can use the designer to do whatever you need to (e.g. change column sizes, etc.), but when the program is run, the data source is changed to be the shared one.  It seems to work.

Comment: I think it's safer to just delete the generated instance of MyDataSet from the second form and replace it with your own instance of MyDataSet, which you declare in SecondForm.cs and initialize in the constructor, using the passed-in argument.
To be on the safe side, compare SecondForm.designer.cs before and after deleting myDataSet and add any relevant lines deleted from InitializeComponent to your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `BindingSource` in the designer, then set its source to the DataSet in the designer.

You can then change your form's constructor to set the `BindingSource`'s source to a shared DataSet.

Comment: This makes it sound like I am either throwing away the original BindingSource of the form or that I can't work with the DataGridView in the designer since the designer won't know what the data is.  Or am I missing something?  Is there not some way of selecting a shared BindingSource in the designer?

Comment: @ferzle: No; you throw away the original _DataSet_ of the form.

Comment: It is possible to make your own `BindingSource` class that binds to a shared DataSet (this would need to work at both design-time and at runtime), but it's tricky.

Comment: That is what I meant.  So done this way I create a DataSet and bind it to the second form so I can work with it in the designer, but then in the constructor I bind it to the shared one so it replaces it?  This seems sloppy and I am frustrated that there isn't a slick way to do something that seems so common.

Comment: I ended up updating two fields (`myBindingSource.DataSource` and `myDataSet`) to the shared DataSet.  I can't recall, but I assume both of these fields were created by the designer when I added the data source.

Comment: @ferzle: You should put your final solution in a separate answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I should put it as part of yours since your answer inspired it.  Did you delete it?  Can I get the content back?